# LSTM model loss fluctuates then goes high, accuracy increases overall

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm creating an LSTM time-series model.  I've been working on this model for 6 months off and on doing research and development.  I finally got the model working and I was optimizing the parameters (batch size, time_steps, dropout rates, learning_rates, layer configurations)  to find the best combination to produce the highest accuracy and lowest loss.  I think I found it but I couldn't get the accuracy better than 67% with a loss of 0.0045 with 200 epochs.  So I decided to run it for 500 epochs.  At epoch 336, the loss goes high, then back and forth but the accuracy keeps increasing overall.  The loss goes as low as 0.001 and the accuracy goes as high as 77%.  Epoch 335 has the optimum result with loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7526.

I'm thinking the model found the gradient decent global minimum at epoch 335 and I shouldn't train past that.  Is this a correct assumption?  I'm sure at some point, a model can be trained too much and it starts to overfit, even with dropout, but at which epoch should you say to yourself, I can't squeeze anymore juice out of this model?  I'm thinking epoch 335 is that point.

What are your thoughts on this?

Here is the model code:

```
TIME_STEP = 8
BATCH_SIZE = 24
EPOCHS = 500
DROPOUT = 0.2
LR = 0.001

 def create_model(self, epochs, batch_size):
    # Initialising the RNN

    model = Sequential()

    # Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
    model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True,
                   batch_size=batch_size, input_shape=(TIME_STEP, self.X_train.shape[2])))

    # Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
    model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))

    # Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
    model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))

    # Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularization
    model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))

    # Adding the output layer
    model.add(Dense(units=64))
    model.add(Dense(units=19))
    model.summary()

    # compile model
    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=LR)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics='accuracy')
    model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Here is the model's output results:

```
    _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (24, 8, 128)              75776     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (24, 8, 128)              131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (24, 8, 128)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (24, 8, 128)              131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (24, 8, 128)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (24, 128)                 131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (24, 128)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (24, 64)                  8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (24, 19)                  1235      
=================================================================
Total params: 480,019
Trainable params: 480,019
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/500
2020-06-29 06:04:06.820326: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-06-29 06:04:07.108240: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
1878/1878 [==============================] - 11s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0077 - accuracy: 0.3931
Epoch 2/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0050 - accuracy: 0.5192
Epoch 3/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 11s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0049 - accuracy: 0.5586

...

At epoch 336, the loss goes high, then back and forth but the accuracy keeps increasing overall:

Epoch 334/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7494
Epoch 335/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7526
Epoch 336/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 9.9849e-04 - accuracy: 0.7586
Epoch 337/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7488
Epoch 338/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7536

...

Epoch 357/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 0.7582
Epoch 358/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 9.8537e-04 - accuracy: 0.7578
Epoch 359/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7531
Epoch 360/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7544
Epoch 361/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7525
Epoch 362/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 0.7552
Epoch 363/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 9.7085e-04 - accuracy: 0.7605
Epoch 364/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 9.8991e-04 - accuracy: 0.7590
Epoch 365/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7516
Epoch 366/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7551
Epoch 367/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 9.9060e-04 - accuracy: 0.7594
Epoch 368/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 0.7570
Epoch 369/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 9.9755e-04 - accuracy: 0.7609
Epoch 370/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7534
Epoch 371/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 9.9546e-04 - accuracy: 0.7583
Epoch 372/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7563
Epoch 373/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 9.9044e-04 - accuracy: 0.7623
Epoch 374/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.7536
Epoch 375/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 0.7579

...

Epoch 479/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 9.2746e-04 - accuracy: 0.7688
Epoch 480/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 0.7609
Epoch 481/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 8.5944e-04 - accuracy: 0.7723
Epoch 482/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.1934e-04 - accuracy: 0.7673
Epoch 483/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.7588e-04 - accuracy: 0.7662
Epoch 484/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 8.6872e-04 - accuracy: 0.7723
Epoch 485/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 0.7622
Epoch 486/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.4036e-04 - accuracy: 0.7686
Epoch 487/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 9.0135e-04 - accuracy: 0.7706
Epoch 488/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 8.9095e-04 - accuracy: 0.7730
Epoch 489/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.2459e-04 - accuracy: 0.7706
Epoch 490/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.1704e-04 - accuracy: 0.7713
Epoch 491/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.0080e-04 - accuracy: 0.7689
Epoch 492/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.4111e-04 - accuracy: 0.7675
Epoch 493/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 7ms/step - loss: 9.1599e-04 - accuracy: 0.7707
Epoch 494/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 8.4016e-04 - accuracy: 0.7793
Epoch 495/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.5818e-04 - accuracy: 0.7626
Epoch 496/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.2504e-04 - accuracy: 0.7692
Epoch 497/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.0894e-04 - accuracy: 0.7669
Epoch 498/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.2687e-04 - accuracy: 0.7701
Epoch 499/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 12s 6ms/step - loss: 9.1015e-04 - accuracy: 0.7714
Epoch 500/500
1878/1878 [==============================] - 13s 7ms/step - loss: 8.6003e-04 - accuracy: 0.7734
```

Here is the testing data plot.  The prediction is in blue:

[image]

Comment: is this a classification or a regression problem?

Comment: This is time-series data.  I'm predicting future prices using hourly data points.  A regression problem.

Comment: ok... what's the sense of using accuracy as a metric in a regression problem?

Comment: I'm following open-sourced code.  What metrics should I be tracking?

Comment: So what does the accuracy value in this model mean?  What is it measuring?  Can you elaborate on the sense of using accuracy as a metric in a regression problem?

Comment: accuracy has completely no sense in a regression problem: https://machinelearningmastery.com/metrics-evaluate-machine-learning-algorithms-python/

Comment: Thanks Marco, I appreciate that. I have been following Dr Brownlee but missed that post.  I'll try R squared instead.

Comment: yes... now it has a sense ;-)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani: Here is an article from Jason Brownlee that uses accuracy as a metric in an LSTM model.  I believe this is where I got the idea to use accuracy in an LSTM in the first place.  I'm experiencing cognitive dissonance now.  :-)  https://machinelearningmastery.com/diagnose-overfitting-underfitting-lstm-models/

Comment: It's a demo blog post ;-)

Comment: But you referenced that blog site earlier in your comments: "accuracy has completely no sense in a regression problem."  So I'm a little confused here.  I guess I'll fire off a question to Dr. Brownlee in his post for further explanation.  I'll let you know what he says.